# HTTP status for @PutMapping and @DeleteMapping for Spring Boot REST API?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

I was using `HttpStatus.OK` for all of my requests in Spring Bot Controller. But I realized that it is good to return a proper Http status and started to use the followings:

```
GET --> Ok
POST -> Created
PUT --> Ok ???
DELETE --> NoContent ???
```

But I am not sure regarding to PUT and DELETE, some people suggest using NoContent for DELETE and Ok for PUT. But I am confused and no idea which one is suitable.

So, which Status codes should I use for PUT and DELETE ? Here is an example usage for my DELETE, but I am not sure if we can return body when Status code is NoContent (is it meaningful?)

```
@DeleteMapping("/categories/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse<CommandResponse>> deleteById(@PathVariable long id) {
    final CommandResponse response = categoryService.deleteById(id);
    return ResponseEntity
            .status(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
            .body(new ApiResponse<>(Instant.now(clock).toEpochMilli(), SUCCESS, response));
}
```

**Update:** Based on the situatin, I think the following implementations are ok:

***#1:***

```
@DeleteMapping("/categories/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse<Void>> deleteById(@PathVariable long id) {
    categoryService.deleteById(id);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new ApiResponse<>(Instant.now(clock).toEpochMilli(), SUCCESS));
}
```

***#2:***

```
@DeleteMapping("/categories/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse<Void>> deleteById(@PathVariable long id) {
    categoryService.deleteById(id);
    return ResponseEntity
            .status(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
            .build();
}
```

Comment: I would if I get the confirmation about the last points that I have been trying to ask for hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in [Http Protocol RFC 2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6)

> **9.6 PUT**
>
> If an existing resource is modified, either the 200 (OK) or 204 (No
> Content) response codes SHOULD be sent to indicate successful
> completion of the request.

Also

> **9.7 DELETE**
>
> A successful response SHOULD be 200 (OK) if the response includes an entity describing the status, 202 (Accepted) if the action
> has not yet been enacted, or 204 (No Content) if the action has been
> enacted but the response does not include an entity.

**Edit**: To clarify. The part in delete operation that describes the status 200 (OK) expects an entity not of the actual business deleted or not in database, but another object entity which is able to describe the status of the delete action (DONE, PENDING, FAILED...).

Comment: What about my `@DeleteMapping()` usage examples for bot situation? Are they ok?

Comment: @fredrick the second example you have for `@DeleteMapping()` `return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT).build();` seems the most appropriate.

Comment: Yes, but what I want to understand: **1.** When I need to return HttpStatus.OK, the the first example in my update is also a proper example, right?

Comment: **2.** I use `ResponseEntity<ApiResponse<Void>>` as teh return type for my second example. Is that ok with ``Void` ?

Comment: @fredrick For delete operation you should return 204 in case the `categoryService.deleteById(id);` is an imidiate process and succeeds. If it is an async process which will be executed later in that case you need to return 200 Ok

Comment: @fredrick for PutMapping you can use both 204 and 200. If you return `void` then you should have status 204. If you return the updated object then you should have status 200. It is up to you and your client to decide which of the 2 suits you best.

Comment: Ok, I understood. But it is also possible to return OK as status and I just want to know if those implementations are ok. So, could you please clarify me about these 2 questions one by one?

Comment: @fredrick check my last comment I have answered both your questions

Comment: But I did not mean that with the 2 question. Those are in my comment. Here are >>>

Comment: Reagrding to DeleteMappings in my Update, >>> **1.** When I need to return HttpStatus.OK, the the first example in my update is also a proper example, right?

Comment: 2. I use ResponseEntity<ApiResponse<Void>> as teh return type for my second example. Is that ok with ``Void` ? –

Comment: @fredrick please do not spam in comments. The comments are useful for OP as well. Please try to form concrete comments which can be read from other users and provide value. As to your question the number 1 can be used for PutMapping with status Ok if you provide as a return the updated object. To your number 2 for PutMapping with status 204 is also ok if you use `void` as return type.

Comment: I think you totally misunderstood "update" s... I mean **Update** in my question (see last part please), not updating an entity. But you repeated the same answer and that is why I also had to repeat the same questions :)  Any idea?

Comment: By the way, voted up for your useful helps. Thanks a lot amigo.

Comment: @fredrick my 1st comment in this thread already answered this question of yours.

Comment: It was not clear and just would like to get clarified. **1.** The second method in the **Update section** with `ResponseEntity<ApiResponse<Void>>` return type is ok, right? **2.** If I want to return HTTP Status OK, then the first method in the **Update section** is also ok, right?

Comment: @fredrick I realize that you are somewhat new here, but you should understand that SO is not a discussion forum or platform. Lengthy discussions in comments should be avoided; for that, there is a [chat feature](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/new).

Comment: I would avoid, but in order to just get a confirmation, I had to repeat the same questions multiple times. After reading the answer, I feel that my questions are not read.

Comment: @fredrick  `The second method in the Update section with ResponseEntity<ApiResponse<Void>> return type is ok, right? 2. If I want to return HTTP Status OK, then the first method in the Update section is also ok, right?` 1 seems ok you return void and you have status 204, so is correct. 2 seems not ok, in delete operations according to Rest best practices you should not return an object like you do.

Comment: Thans for reply, but in the part you shared: **"9.7 DELETE: A successful response SHOULD be 200 (OK) if the response includes an entity describing the status ..."** and for this reason I thought we can also use the second approach for delete if we need to return something. Is that wrong?

Comment: @fredrick if your action `categoryService.deleteById(id);` is already enacted by the time you return the response which I think is your case here, then according to best REST practices the 204 no content status without any returned entity is more appropriate

Comment: @fredrick also read the documentation better. In delete operations in case of 200 Ok status, the response should be a message describing what the state of the action was. Not an actual object of your entity. Read also here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/DELETE.

Comment: yes, I read and updated #1 st approach. Do you mean something like that (I just return SUCCESS as message belonging to my `ApiResponse` class and did not return entity, etc. Is that ok for now?

Comment: @fredrick your updated code looks ok, but keep in mind in REST services you are not obligated to do something. You follow the best practices but this is not an obligation and many times you may do something out of best practices for some reasons. This is also reality as well. Please accept the answer if you have solved your problem.

Comment: I agree with you and normally I will use the second approach with `NO_CONTENT` response. Why I was asking the first approach is in case I need to return status of `OK`. And of course I always try to follow the best practices as much as possible. Thanks a lot for your helps.

Answer (score 2):

A 204 (No Content) response should not include a body; "No Content" means *no content*. 204 is pretty standard for a DELETE response (when it succeeds of course), but I also see 200 OK.

For PUT requests that succeed, it's typical to return a 200 response status with the updated resource (entity, etc) as the body. That saves clients from making another round-trip GET to the server to get the updated resource.

By the way, Spring provides an annotation to specify the response status code so you don't have to be so verbose in the code. For example:

```java
@DeleteMapping("/categories/{id}")
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
public void deleteById(@PathVariable long id) {
    categoryService.deleteById(id);
}
```

Comment: Actually I do not prefer using annotation (`@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)`) above the method as the other method has not and defined return status differently.

Comment: You can use that annotation on all methods if you want; saves some extra boilerplate code when constructing your responses.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these nice explanations. Then based on the situation, I think the implementations in my Update are ok for DELETE mapping. Right? –

Comment: What about this -->>> Thanks a lot for these nice explanations. Then based on the situation, I think the implementations in my Update are ok for DELETE mapping. Right? –

Comment: Yes, although I find them to be unnecessarily verbose. That's a matter of taste, though; not correctness.

Comment: I updated the second method and as I need to `ResponseEntity<ApiResponse<Void>>`, I think this time it is ok. What do you think amigo?

Answer (score 1):

For PUT

- HTTP status 201 if the entry does not exist and is created
- HTTP status 200 or HTTP status 204 if entry exists and is updated

For DELETE

- HTTP status 200

visit   [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PUT) for further details

Comment: A 201 (Created) response would be incorrect or at least misleading for a PUT, which should be for _updates_ to an existing resource, not creating new resources.

Comment: Voted up for your useful helps. Thanks a lot amigo.

Comment: PUT should not generally be used for creating resources, that should be a POST. PUT should address a specific resource for _updating_ (usually by ID). Thus, a 201 response is not appropriate for a PUT.